# Macro to calculate cash balance in Excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table with the transactions (Amount in and Amount Out). I need an macro to calculate the closing balance. Can you please guide me.

[image]

I have tried this macro but give an arror

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
     Dim oNewRow As ListRow, rng As Range
     Set rng = Sheets("Bank Sheet").Range("Table2")
     Set oNewRow = Sheets("BankSheet").Range("Table2").ListObject.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
        With rng
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 5) = TxtBoxBkAmount.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 6) = TxtBoxBkAmount.Value
'Calculate the Balance
      If oNewRow.Row = 11 Then
          oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-3]C+([@[Amount In]]-[@[Amount Out]])"
      Else
          oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-3]C+([@[Amount In]]-[@[Amount Out]])"
      End IfEnd With
End Sub
```

I am using this macro to delete Rows in the table:
Dim ws As Worksheet, Table As ListObject
Set ws = Sheets("Bank Sheet")
Set Table = ws.ListObjects("Table2")
If Table.ListRows.Count > 2 Then
Table.DataBodyRange.Delete
end if

Comment: What error do you get and on what line?

Comment: Why do you need a macro? cell G11 "=G88+E11-F11. Then G12 "=G11+E12-F12" etc.

Comment: The error I got is : Run time Error '438' (Object doesn't support this property or method). I want to use macro instead of sheet's formula because the table will be cleared and reused. When Data range cleared with macro, the formula is also deleted! Also after data range is cleared and enter new transaction, it jumps the 1st row of the Table2.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is using formula like this:

for cell

- G11 `=G8+E11-F11`.
- G12 and below `=G11+E12-F12`

But I'm assuming that your issue is with default [Calculated formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-calculated-columns-in-an-excel-table-873fbac6-7110-4300-8f6f-aafa2ea11ce8) for the column in table

To address this, you can add a IF statement to check if the rows is the 1st row in table and change the formula accordingly like this:

```
= IF (G10="Balance", G8+([@[Amount In]]-[@[Amount Out]]), G11+([@[Amount In]]-[@[Amount Out]]))
```

Add this formula in cell G11 and Overwrite all cells in column with this formula

Comment: This = IF (G10="Balance", G8+([@[Amount In]]-[@[Amount Out]]), G11+([@[Amount In]]-[@[Amount Out]])) works quite well. The problem is when you clear the Data range using macro, it clears also the formula. I using User form to populate the Table(Sheet). Thank you for your assistance.